# Read from a specific row onwards from Excel File

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have got a Excel file having around 7000 rows approx to read. And Excel file contains Table of Contents and the actual contents data in details below.

I would like to avoid all rows for Table of Content and start from actual content data to read. This is because if I need to read data for "CPU_INFO" the loop and search string occurrence twice 1] from Table of Content and 2] from actual Content.

So I would like to know if there is any way I can point to Start Row Index to start reading data content for Excel File , thus skipping whole of Table Of Content Section?

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 1):

As taken from the [Apache POI documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator):

> In some cases, when iterating, you need full control over how missing or blank rows or cells are treated, and you need to ensure you visit every cell and not just those defined in the file. (The CellIterator will only return the cells defined in the file, which is largely those with values or stylings, but it depends on Excel).
>
> In cases such as these, you should fetch the first and last column information for a row, then call getCell(int, MissingCellPolicy) to fetch the cell. Use a [MissingCellPolicy](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html) to control how blank or null cells are handled.

If we take the example code from that documentation, and tweak it for your requirement to start on row 7000, and assuming you want to not go past 15k rows, we get:

```
// Decide which rows to process
int rowStart = Math.min(7000, sheet.getFirstRowNum());
int rowEnd = Math.max(1500, sheet.getLastRowNum());

for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
   Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);

   int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
      }
   }
}
```